# Critical Error message on visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I open my Visual Studio 2012 and then go to database explorer.  I open my database, then when I open one of the Stored Procedures I got an error. It is Critical Error, I have to close my Visual Studio any time I open the Stored Procedure. I can't do anything.

help please,

#### note that I am using vs 2012

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Download and install SQL Server Data Tools : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj650015

Source : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/002833be-f0f5-41be-8de4-a08a8bc02f31/critical-error-on-visual-studio-data-connection?forum=vstsdb